# Implementing Multi-GPU using the Unity Engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, multi-gpu, directx-12

I am currently working on a quite large, graphicaly demanding Unity project. So I decided that I want to implement a Multi-GPU approach in order to get enough performance to run my build. While researching I found out that implementing Multi-GPU isn’t as easy as I first thought. There are currently many conflicting oppinions on if realtime Multi-GPU is even still possible at this time. One thing that has held my hopes up [is this blog post](https://developer.nvidia.com/explicit-multi-gpu-programming-directx-12) by Nvidea . It explains how it is possible to create your own Multi-GPU solution using DX12.
If anyone knows anything about this, my exact Questions are:

1. Is there any way to implement Multi-GPU in Unity?
2. If yes, how would I go about implementing Multi-GPU into my project
   using DX12 perferably?
3. Is there any automatic/template Multi-GPU implementation I could
   use?

Thanks for any Help!

Comment: For multi-GPU implementation in DX12, I think what you're looking for is the [D3D12 
MultiGPU Starter Library, aka Affinity Layer](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Libraries/D3DX12AffinityLayer).